# nMDS using Bray-Curtis - plotting in groups

Tags: r

I am having trouble with the my nMDS plot. I have ran the nMDS ok and have plotted the data using the script below BUT I cant seem to get it to group by colour and/or shape based on my four different treatment options. Can anyone see where I am going wrong? The last plot comes up empty.

```
library("vegan")

data_1 <-Spp_Abund[,4:10]
data_2 <-Spp_Abund[,1:3]

nMDS <-metaMDS(data_1, distance = "bray", k=2)

plot(nMDS)

co=c("red", "blue", "green", "black")
shape=c(1,2,3,4)

plot(nMDS$points, col=co[data_2$Treatment], pch=shape[data_2$Treatment], cex=1.2, main="", xlab="axis 1", ylab="axis 2)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thankyou

Comment: My data is looking at 7 species (columns 4:10). I have 16 sites (16 rows) that have been categorised by 4 different treatments (column3)

Answer (score 0):

1. The last parameter "ylab" has unclosed quotation marks.
2. You need to convert the shapes as numeric before you can pass it. So this should work:

```
plot(nMDS$points, col=co[data_2$Treatment], pch=shape[as.numeric(data_2$Treatment)], cex=1.2, main="", xlab="axis 1", ylab="axis 2")
```

3. Alternatively, you could use ggplot2 like in this example:
   https://jkzorz.github.io/2019/06/06/NMDS.html

Good luck!